# CSS media queries for floating grid columns?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've been tasked with making an existing website responsive.  It's using a bootstrap style grid system and is quite a mess.  The following is a snippet of code.

```
<div class="col-1 col-2 col-3">
  <div class="left">Left Column</div>
</div>

<div class="col-1 col-2 col-3">
  <div class="right">Right Column</div>
</div>
```

I can add media queries but because the "left" and "right" columns have both been wrapped in these column creating divs, **with existing widths applied**.  What's the best semantic way of rewriting the code (while keeping all the existing column styles), so that I can apply my own styles using media queries?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I guess I wasn't wrapping my head around it being a parent selector since I was trying to select the child div.  I see now that it was!  I will try and edit the question and see if I can approach it differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `id` to them

```
<div id="left" class="col-1 col-2 col-3">
  <div class="left">Left Column</div>
</div

<div id="right" class="col-1 col-2 col-3">
  <div class="right">Right Column</div>
</div>
```

Comment: *and unfortunately editing the HTML is not an option* and :has() will work nowhere

Comment: I was able to figure out a way to access the HTML to edit it, but I want to make sure I don't completely rewrite it so it breaks elsewhere.

Comment: @Rarblack you need to check the support before advising sometihng, scroll down to the link you shared and see that `:has()` has 0 support